# Serialization of DatagramPacket

Tags: serialization

i want to know ,how can i serialize the DatagramPacket ... in my code , i have two clients that   has interaction through a server . client1  put the client2Packet in serverPacket and send it to server and server extract the client2Packet and send it to client2 .(some how simulating of VPN )but all the time i am faced by  "java.io.NotSerializableException" , i created a class that implement interface "Serializable" , but still .....so , please help me :)   " first i want to konw is that possible , if it is please tell me how ,thanks , i put my codes below : `

`enter code here

```
package puya

`import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

public class Client1 {
    public static int client1Port=16000;
    public static int serverPort=16001;
    public static int client2Port=16002;
    public static int max_Size=255;
    public static int maximum_Size=300;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, ClassNotFoundException {

        DatagramSocket sock= new DatagramSocket(client1Port);
        byte[] data1=new byte[max_Size];
        byte[] Data1=new byte[maximum_Size];


        ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PrintStream pout = new PrintStream (bout);
        System.out.println("client1 side : please say sth : ");
        System.out.println();
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        String mess=scan.nextLine();
        pout.print (mess);
        System.out.println();
        data1 = bout.toByteArray();
        DatagramPacket clientPacket=new DatagramPacket(data1,data1.length);
        InetAddress remote_addr =InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        clientPacket.setAddress(remote_addr);
        clientPacket.setPort(client2Port);

        SerializablePacket sp=new SerializablePacket(clientPacket); 


        // Now time to put this packet into another packet :

        ByteArrayOutputStream bStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oop=new ObjectOutputStream(bStream); 
        oop.writeObject(sp);
        System.out.println("packet is going inside of another packet ");
        System.out.println();
        Data1 =bStream.toByteArray();

        DatagramPacket serverPacket=new DatagramPacket(Data1,Data1.length);
        serverPacket.setAddress(remote_addr);
        serverPacket.setPort(serverPort);
        // End of puting one packet into another packet step

        System.out.println("server is ready to send the packet ");

        sock.send(serverPacket);
        System.out.println("server sent the packet");




    }

}



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////




package puya;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;

public class Server {


    public static int client1Port=16000;
    public static int serverPort=16001;
    public static int client2Port=16002;
    public static int max_Size=255;
    public static int maximum_Size=300;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, ClassNotFoundException {


        byte[] data1=new byte[max_Size];
        byte[] Data1=new byte[maximum_Size];
        SerializablePacket sp=new SerializablePacket();
        DatagramSocket sock= new DatagramSocket(serverPort);

        DatagramPacket serverPacket=new DatagramPacket(Data1,Data1.length);
        DatagramPacket client2Packet=new DatagramPacket(data1,data1.length);
        System.out.println("server is waiting to receive one packet from client ");
        sock.receive(serverPacket);
        System.out.println("server received one");

        ByteArrayInputStream bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(serverPacket.getData());
        ObjectInputStream oos = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
        sp=(SerializablePacket)oos.readObject();

        client2Packet=sp.getDatagramPacket();

        System.out.println("The client packet is extracted from server packet");

        sock.send(client2Packet);
        System.out.println("server is sending client2packet");
            }

}

    enter code here

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

package puya;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;

public class Client2 {

    public static int serverPort=16001;
    public static int client2Port=16002;
    public static int max_Size=255;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        byte[] data1=new byte[max_Size];
        DatagramSocket sock= new DatagramSocket(client2Port);


        DatagramPacket client2Packet=new DatagramPacket(data1,data1.length);
        System.out.println("client 2 is waiting for receiving serverPacket");
        sock.receive(client2Packet);
        System.out.println("The packet is received");


        ByteArrayInputStream bais=new ByteArrayInputStream(client2Packet.getData());

        for (int i=0;i<client2Packet.getLength();i++)
        {
            int data=bais.read();

            if(data == -1)
            {
                break ;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.print((char)data);
            }
        }

    }

}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    enter code here

package puya;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;

public class SerializablePacket implements Serializable {


    public DatagramPacket datagramPacket;

    public DatagramPacket getDatagramPacket() {
        return datagramPacket;
    }

    public void setDatagramPacket(DatagramPacket datagramPacket) {
        this.datagramPacket = datagramPacket;
    }

    public SerializablePacket()
    {}

    public SerializablePacket(DatagramPacket datagramPacket)
    {
        this.datagramPacket=datagramPacket;
    }






}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DatagramPacket isn't Serializable. Wrapping it inside a Serializable class doesn't change that. You should *copy* its *members* into your Serializable class, specifically the data, offset, and length. Hard to see why you would want to serialize the address and port, but if you need those too, include them.

Comment: actually i said , i want to simulate a light weight version of VPN by putting one packet into another , is that possible at all to put a packet into another one ...

Comment: Of course, but that doesn't make it Serializable if it wasn't already, as I have already stated.